# How to correct display formula in ckeditor when edit content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using ckeditor with math formula, when I insert new math formula, it can good display but when I edit the content in editor, it seem not can correct display or read format of math formula...

My source:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)']]}});</script>
</head>

<body>  
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="640" height="650">                                   
            <textarea name="ir1" id="ir1" rows="1" cols="10" style="width:580px; height:600px; min-width:400px; min-height:50px; display:none;"></textarea>                     
                <script>
                    var ir1 = CKEDITOR.replace('ir1');
                              CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'mathjax';
                              CKEDITOR.config.mathJaxLib = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
                              CKFinder.setupCKEditor(ir1, 'libraries/ckfinder/');
                </script>                       
        </td>           
    </tr>
</table>
<body>
```

this is result when edit content:
[image]

within 'ir' is string of math formula..

So, How to correct display format of math formula in ckeditor when edit content ?

Thanks..

Comment: oh no, nobody reply.. :((

Comment: Do you insert math formula via MathJax dialog? Are there any errors in the browser console?